# Interjection of exasperation or frustration when something is not working properly

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

When I am exasperated or frustrated when something is not working properly. Not like *shit* or *fuck*, those are just "something bad is happening", and too broad. I want something that's more like signifying annoyance, a "this is really getting to me" type of thing. Is there a word for this?

I have heard Chinese people say "aiiyaaa" in this scenario but I am not sure if there is an English equivalent for this.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Captain Haddock only ever used 'Blisterin' Barnacles!' when at the end of his tether. But then he was usually at the end of his tether.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth 'Aunt Fanny' of Enid Blyton creation might have said 'bother'!

Comment: What's wrong with a long, drawn-out guttural "AAARRRGHH!"? Works for me! :-)

Comment: @Kristina Looks very similar in print to the long, drawn out, higher pitched "AAARRRGHH!" when one sidesteps a bramble and ends up in a large patch of nettles.

Comment: @WS2 Ah, happy memories. After Quentin had blown up the library again, no doubt.

Comment: Something-bad-is-happening!

Comment: Why say anything? Who are you saying it to? What outcome do you expect to achieve? If I may intuit that nobody in particular is listening, that you wish to relieve frustration, and want to get to a more positive outcome, then a slightly humorous phrase like "I'm ready for the alternate ending now!" may help.

Comment: @KristinaLopez- I think I've seen something similar at the back of the cave of Caerbannog carved upon the very living rock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list which might prove helpful to you. I'm sorry the list comprises more than just one-word expressions of exasperation.

> - "Oh,  bother!"
> - "Saints preserve us!"
> - "Give me grace!"
> - "Fiddlesticks!"
> - "Screw it!"
> - "Give me strength!"
> - "Lord!"
> - "I give up!"
> - "Blast!"
> - "For Pete's sake!"
> - "For crying out loud!"
> - "Give me a break!"
> - "Why me?"
> - "Good night nurse!" (This is a strange one I picked up decades ago, and I find myself using it quite frequently. I seriously doubt you will find it in any dictionary or book of expressions, but I like it. It works for me!)
> - "Good grief!" (Charlie Brown's mantra, from Charles Schulz's comic strip, Peanuts)
> - "Forgive me, Lord, for what I am about to do!"

Answer (score 2):

`Damn!` or `Damn it!` are relevant.

Comment: no those are more like the other two swear words. I am looking for exasperation specific, not a blanket utterance for bad things. It would be especially good if it can be drawn out. like aiyaaaaaa

Comment: I disagree. These almost always signal exasperation; your two suggestions might be used when disgusted or alarmed.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for an [interjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) like "ugh", "psht" or "tch".

Comment: 'Ugh' surely is a sign of disgust.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly **Shazbot?** It originated on Robin Williams' TV series [Mork and Mindy:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy)

From [Wiktionary:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shazbot)

> An excited utterance used to convey disappointment, particularly as a euphemism for sh*t.

And from [Urban Dictionary:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ShazBot)

> Generally used as a substitute curse-word; a euphemism.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is like your "aiiyaaa", but I write, and say (when profanity is not allowable, like at work)

> AAaarrrgh!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *Aye Yai Yai* ([mentalfloss.com](http://mentalfloss.com/article/52790/where-did-phrase-aye-yai-yai-come)) is not uncommon to a Chicagoan; most likely thanks to our Spanish population. Whatever its meaning is I don't know but that doesn't matter; I know what was *meant*.

Do abbreviations count? no? Well, then **FFS**!

Answer (score 0):

Jesu Cristo - my personal exclamation in such instances.

While in Thailand I often heard something akin to the  "aiiyaaa" cited above and even use that myself sometimes. Maybe in Thai more - "aheeee"

Comment: This is an informative answer, but it would be more helpful to the OP and the site if you could reference third-party authorities, over and above your personal experiences.

Answer (score 0):

> Doh!

I believe this is the most accurate English translation.

Answer (score 0):

How about a touch of humor? e.g. ;'Damn, damn, double damn...and a full pint of damn for the weekend!' Credit to Peter (Hugh Laurie) and John (Stephen Fry) on "A Bit of Fry and Laurie".